# Transferring variable from batch to VBScript file returns empty

Tags: variables, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to transfer a variable from a batch file that opens a telnet session to a VB script that runs when the telnet session is open:

```
echo Welcome to Xyplex Server Port Reset

set /p whichXplex= Which Xyplex server is your device connected too: 1 or 2 ?
echo.
set /p "whichPort= Which port do you want to reset:" 
echo.

REM Pass the variable portnumber to script 
cscript.exe //NoLogo loginInXyplex.vbs /portname:"%whichPort%"
```

.....open  a telnet session and run the script

The script runs during the telnet session, where I try to print the variable passed from the batch file:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
OBJECT.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "username{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
......etc

'Get the port number sent from batch file
port = WScript.Arguments.Named("portname")


    OBJECT.SendKeys  "Port number selected is: " & port
```

But the output is always blank:

> Port number selected is:

Where is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This may help another newbie to vb scripting:
Issue iscalling two scripts in batch file, when calling the first it blocks the excution flow so nothing is sent to the second script running during the telnet session.
Using command

> `start /b "" cscript //nologo ...............`

will run the first script in parrell with subsequent commands (which actually created more issues in my situation so I ended up modifying the design).