# Telnet user input to vb Script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, user-input, telnet

I am trying to get a port number to reset in telnet from user input.
I have tried using a batch file to pass the user inputted variable onto a vb script that thn outputs to a telnet session but this does not work : see  [Transferring variable from batch to VBScript file returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505113/transferring-variable-from-batch-to-vbscript-file-returns-empty)

So my alternative is to look at  user input during the telent session and use this input to store a varaible in the vb script and then exceute the LO PO function with it.

Have searched around allot but cannot find any solution or if this is even possible.

Any suggestions appreacited.

EDIT:
So far have tried getting user input from command line in a batch file and passing to the script which is called in the batch file after telnet is called:

```
echo Welcome to Xyplex Server Port Reset

set /p whichXplex= Which Xyplex server is your device connected too: 1 or 2 ?
echo.
set /p "whichPort= Which port do you want to reset:" 
echo.

REM Pass the variable portnumber to script 
cscript.exe //NoLogo loginInXyplex.vbs /portname:"%whichPort%"
REM ....start telnet.......call loginInXyplex.vbs...
```

The script loginInXyplex.vbs attempts to retrieve the variable (portName: %whichPort%) passed from the batch file:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
OBJECT.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "username{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
......etc

'Get the port number sent from batch file
port = WScript.Arguments.Named("portname")


    OBJECT.SendKeys  "Port number selected is: " & port
```

..but the output for 'port' is always empty

Comment: Please provide the script you have so far

Comment: Hi, all the code is posted on the link ref in question, didn't see point in re posting it again but can if needed

Comment: `cscript` blocks the execution flow so it doesn't send anything to `telnet`. Try `start /b "" cscript //nologo ...............` which will run it in parallel with the subsequent commands.

Comment: Also, have you not fixed the issue with the wrong syntax of `WScript.Arguments.Named.Item()` invocation?

Comment: Yes fixed that issue. So your suggestion is : start /b "" cscript //NoLogo loginInXyplex.vbs /portname:"%whichPort%" ? What does the start /b do?

Comment: Just run `start /?` as usual on the command prompt to see the list of command line switches and explanation. Also I've already explained what it will do so I don't know what to add to that.

Comment: Thanks that worked I got the variable in the script file, however seem to have multiple scripts running at once as script file is always called after telnet.exe is called and called when we want to transfer the variable

Comment: Do I need to start telnet and over call to script field with start /b ? Can't seem to reverse  this issue now

Comment: Well, edit the question and add the code you're having problems with. Until now it was all just guesswork from my side which isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: Not to worry I re-designedidea and left out the transfer of varible from bat to script, thanks for the help